# How to add the Doppler shift to a discrete-time signal with oversampling? and what's the difference between Doppler shift and Doppler rate?

Tags: discrete-signals, digital-communications, doppler

Mathematically, the Doppler shift in a continuous-time baseband signal can be written as

$$x(t)=s(t)\,e^{j2\pi f_dt}$$

where $f_d$ is the Doppler shift. In the discrete-time, this becomes

$$x[nT_s] = s(nT_s)\,e^{j2\pi f_dnT_s}$$

What does this become with an oversampling factor of $K$? In a code I have it multiplies the oversampled signal with  $e^{j2\pi f_dnT_s/K}$. But why?

Another question, what's the difference between Doppler shift and Doppler rate? I saw a code that uses Doppler rate from the Doppler shift, and then apply the Doppler rate to the signal.